# Sum all columns in each column in csv using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The program I have written generally has done what I've wanted it to do - for the most part. To add totals of each column. My dataframe uses the csv file format. My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot


class ColumnCalculation:
"""This houses the functions for all the column manipulation calculations"""

def max_electricity(self):
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
    print(df)


df = pd.read_csv("2011-onwards-city-elec-consumption.csv")
ColumnCalculation.max_electricity(df)
```

Also my dataset (I didn't know how to format it properly)

[image: dataset]

The code nicely adds up all totals into a total column at the bottom of each column, except when it comes to the last column(2017)(image below):[image]

I am not sure the program does is, I've tried to use different formatting options like `.iloc` or `.ix` but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I have also tried adding each column individually (below):

```
def max_electricity(self):
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    df.loc['Total', '2011'] = df['2011'].sum()
    df.loc['Total', '2012'] = df['2012'].sum()
    df.loc['Total', '2013'] = df['2013'].sum()
    df.loc['Total', '2014'] = df['2014'].sum()
    df.loc['Total', '2015'] = df['2015'].sum()
    df.loc['Total', '2016'] = df['2016'].sum()
    df.loc['Total', '2017'] = df['2017'].sum()
    print(df)
```

But I receive an error, as I assume this would be too much? I've tried to figure this out for a good hour and a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last column isn't being parsed as floats, but strings.

To fix this, try casting to numeric before summing:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')

df['2017'] = df['2017'].map(locale.atoi)
```

Better still, try reading in the data as numeric data. For example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\t', thousands=',')
```

Comment: If I do read the data as numeric data, I get `KeyError: Date`, but also why wouldn't it parse the data as floats as it has done for all the other values?

Comment: I see, so you may have to convert it later, as per my first solution.

Comment: Thank you, I played around with the solution you gave me and if when I wrote `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', thousands=',')` it appeared to work. What exactly does the `thousands=','` do may I ask?